# Decoding APK Files in android

Tags: java, android, encapsulation, dex2jar

I tried to decode a published application from Google Play with its apk file by using `dex2jar and apktool.` I successfully manage to get its source code however, I am wondering why the hell I got this sets of codes(attached image)? I could not clearly get the package/s and the activity names of this app. I need it badly.

[image]

Is it because of encapsulation? How can I get the real code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Guy used the ProGuard for this APK. You can not do reverse engineering after that easily.

ProGuard is file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator.

Answer (score 4):

Check this [Link](http://bit.ly/1e3Ydlc) how to crack the Apk. But you won't get the complete code at all.. Because everyone uses ProGuard as @Williams said.

Partially you can understand if you're a more than a Geek

Use [this](http://bit.ly/1bnIxL3) tool to get the drawable like png and jpeg files.

To use formatter make a backup of you're apk before

1. Select the apk
2. Then give the format as .rar or .zip
3. then extract the new archived file to see the drawables

[Download Formatter](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4tyir6rp89cd999/install_formatter.exe)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I did this procedure in decoding the apk and that's why I ended up in the attached image...